# Using OffsetDateTime with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to transform an OffsetDateTime object into JSON format using `ObjectMapper`. Instead of using the `toString()` of `OffsetDateTime`, `ObjectMapper` serializes it as an object.

In other words:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;


public class JavaTimerExampleTask{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("The format I want: " + time);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String map = "";
        try {
            map = mapper.writeValueAsString(time);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("ObjectMapper returns:");
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Now, the output is:

The format I want: 2015-12-10T15:01:39.117+02:00

ObjectMapper returns:

```
    {
    "offset": {
        "totalSeconds": 7200,
        "id": "+02:00",
        "rules": {
            "fixedOffset": true,
            "transitionRules": [],
            "transitions": []
        }
    },
    "dayOfMonth": 10,
    "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
    "dayOfYear": 344,
    "hour": 15,
    "minute": 1,
    "month": "DECEMBER",
    "monthValue": 12,
    "nano": 117000000,
    "second": 39,
    "year": 2015
}
```

My question is how do I tell ObjectMapper to apply the date format I want ("The format I want").
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! PhilippS' answer has solved my issue.